# Cannot get nearest neighbors from Nearest

Tags: bugs, crash, nearest

**Bug introduced in 10 and fixed in 10.3**

There still persists the failure to return 30.72 (another bug [according to Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95229/cannot-get-nearest-neighbors-from-nearest#comment257707_95229) but from the developer's point of view it may be a feature).

---

`Nearest[data,x,{n,r}]` is supposed to give the `n` or fewer nearest neighbors to `x` that are within radius `r` of `x`. Example:

```
Nearest[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3.6, {10, 1.5}] (* gives {4, 3, 5} *)
Nearest[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, {10, 2}] (* gives {3, 2, 4, 1, 5}, so it's inclusive *)
```

But this is not working for my data:

```
v = {10.38,17.77,21.25,20.38,14.34,15.7,19.98,20.83,21.82,24.04,23.24,17.89,24.8,23.95,22.61,27.54,20.13,20.68,22.15,14.36,15.71,12.44,14.26,23.04,21.38,16.4,21.53,20.25,25.27,15.05,25.11,18.7,23.98,26.47,17.88,21.59,21.72,18.42,25.2,20.82,21.58,21.35,24.81,20.28,21.81,17.6,16.84,18.66,14.63,22.3,21.6,16.34,18.24,18.7,22.02,18.75,18.57,21.59,19.31,11.79,14.88,20.98,22.15,13.86,23.84,23.94,21.01,19.04,17.33,16.49,21.31,14.64,24.52,15.79,16.52,19.65,10.94,16.15,23.97,18,20.97,15.86,24.91,26.29,15.65,18.52,21.46,24.59,21.8,15.24,24.02,22.76,14.76,18.3,19.83,23.03,17.84,19.94,12.84,19.77,24.98,13.43,20.52,19.4,19.29,15.56,18.33,18.54,19.67,21.26,16.99,20.76,19.65,20.19,15.83,21.53,15.76,16.67,22.91,20.01,10.82,17.12,20.2,10.89,16.39,17.21,24.69,18.91,16.39,25.12,13.29,19.48,21.54,13.93,21.91,22.47,16.67,15.39,17.57,13.39,11.97,18.05,17.31,15.92,14.97,14.65,16.58,18.77,15.18,17.91,20.78,20.7,15.34,13.08,15.34,17.94,20.74,19.46,12.74,12.96,20.18,15.94,18.15,22.22,22.04,19.76,9.71,18.8,24.68,16.95,12.39,19.63,11.89,14.71,15.15,14.45,18.06,20.11,22.22,13.06,21.87,26.57,20.31,14.92,22.41,15.11,18.58,17.19,17.39,15.9,23.12,21.41,18.22,26.86,23.21,16.33,22.29,21.84,22.49,20.22,19.56,19.32,26.67,23.75,18.6,16.68,17.27,20.26,22.54,12.91,22.14,18.94,18.47,25.56,23.81,16.93,18.35,17.48,21.56,32.47,13.16,13.9,17.53,20.25,17.02,13.47,15.46,15.51,23.97,22.33,19.08,27.08,33.81,27.81,15.91,21.25,26.97,21.46,27.85,39.28,15.6,15.04,18.19,23.77,23.5,19.86,17.43,14.11,25.22,14.93,23.56,18.45,19.82,17.08,19.33,17.05,28.77,17.27,23.2,33.56,27.06,23.06,22.13,19.38,22.07,31.12,18.95,21.84,16.21,20.39,16.82,13.04,20.99,15.67,24.48,17.36,14.16,19.98,17.84,15.18,26.6,14.02,18.18,18.77,15.7,18.4,20.76,13.12,19.96,18.89,19.73,19.1,16.02,17.46,13.78,13.27,12.35,18.14,18.17,23.09,18.9,19.89,23.86,18.61,18.16,24.49,15.82,14.4,12.71,13.84,19.11,15.69,13.37,10.72,18.6,16.85,14.08,18.87,18.9,17,16.18,19.66,13.32,21.51,15.21,17.3,12.88,17.93,20.71,21.88,15.51,19.35,19.86,14.78,19.02,21,14.23,21.43,17.53,24.27,16.54,16.84,14.96,21.68,15.45,14.71,18.9,14.74,16.03,14.96,17.07,19.22,17.46,25.74,14.07,19.07,18.59,16.21,15.49,18.32,18.07,21.57,18.84,18.29,16.95,21.78,26.83,18.02,17.25,21.9,23.29,13.21,15.1,17.35,16.07,16.07,20.22,28.21,15.15,18.83,12.96,14.93,22.72,17.48,13.72,23.29,14.09,16.16,15.5,23.21,12.22,16.84,19.97,22.28,17.72,17.18,18.89,17.46,14.83,17.26,21.02,10.91,18.29,16.17,14.95,18.59,14.86,21.37,20.66,17.92,17.57,16.83,21.68,22.11,29.81,21.17,21.7,21.08,12.17,21.41,19.04,13.98,16.02,19.13,19.12,21.28,14.98,21.98,16.62,17.67,22.53,17.68,19.54,21.97,16.94,19.62,19.54,15.98,19.6,15.66,17.2,25.42,15.79,18.32,16.85,24.89,28.03,17.66,19.34,20.52,21.54,25,28.23,13.98,17.15,30.72,29.29,25.25,25.13,28.2,27.15,26.27,26.99,18.36,18.22,20.13,20.74,18.1,23.33,18.18,18.49,28.14,14.93,29.97,15.62,15.73,20.53,16.62,14.59,19.51,18.03,19.24,14.06,17.64,11.28,16.41,16.85,18.82,16.17,20.2,22.44,13.23,20.56,12.83,20.54,20.21,18.17,17.31,17.52,21.24,16.74,24.49,16.32,19.83,12.87,13.14,20.04,17.12,15.7,23.95,14.69,14.7,20.52,13.66,19.07,18.61,20.58,20.26,18.22,16.7,13.9,21.6,19.83,18.68,15.68,13.1,18.75,12.27,13.17,13.44,17.56,20.02,16.33,20.67,17.62,20.86,22.55,24.44,25.49,25.44,14.44,24.99,25.42,28.06,20.7,23.23,16.35,16.58,19.34,24.21,21.48,22.44,29.43,21.94,28.92,27.61,19.59,27.88,22.68,23.93,27.15,29.37,30.62,25.09,22.39,28.25,28.08,29.33,24.54}

Nearest[v, 39.28, 6]
(* gives {39.28, 33.81, 33.56, 32.47, 31.12, 30.72}, which is fine *)

Nearest[v, 39.28, {6, 8.56}]
(* should have given the same answer because 39.28 - 30.72 = 8.56,
   but gives {39.28} instead *)

Nearest[v, 39.28, {6, 9}]
(* same as above, which is even stranger *)
```

I cannot explain this behavior. Any ideas?

Mathematica version: 10.2.0.0

Comment: Your last code kills the kernel when I try to run it.

Comment: @march Not here

Comment: @belisarius. Yeah, I don't know what the deal is there. It pretty much *immediately* kills the kernel, even with your `Rationalize` fix.

Comment: @march Version 9 here. Perhaps it's another v10 bug?

Comment: @march does not crash for me on v10.2

Comment: @belisarius. I'm using v10.0 on a OSX 10.10.5. And when I run it with my copy of v8.0.1, it runs instantly, returning `{39.28, 33.81, 33.56, 32.47, 31.12}` without having to use `Rationalize`. Which means it missed `30.72`.

Comment: Kills the kernel for me on V10.1, Win10.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the development version. As others have pointed out, the `8.56` radius will only return 5 nearest points because `39.28 - 30.72 // InputForm` is `8.560000000000002`.

Comment: The failure to return 30.72 is, in my view, a bug. Reported as such. The developer can always decide it's a feature. In exact arithmetic the error in the last place would not be present, and Nearest probably should not exclude without some allowance for a small number of ULPs. That at least is my opinion.

Comment: Try this data: `v2 = RandomSample[v, 10]~Join~Nearest[v, 39.28, 6] // RandomSample` on your three `Nearest`.

Comment: I just noticed that `(*stranger*)` example, kind of freaking me out.

Answer (score 8):

Specifying the `DistanceFunction` seems to fix it.

```
Nearest[v, 39.28, {All, 8.57}, DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)]
```

> `{39.28, 33.81, 33.56, 32.47, 31.12, 30.72}`

Note that the radius had to be changed also because `Nearest` will return points whose distance are strictly less than the radius.

Comment: Thanks. But the comment on the radius is not true: `Nearest[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, {10, 2}]` will gives `{3, 2, 4, 1, 5}`.

Comment: @ziyuang Hmm that's odd. Odder still is the fact that`Nearest[{1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6}, 3.1, {10, 2}]` returns `{3.1, 4.1, 2.1}` but `Nearest[{1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6}, 3.1, {10, 2}, 
 DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)]` returns `{3.1, 4.1, 2.1, 5.1, 1.1}`. Adjusting `WorkingPrecision` also seems to have no effect on what the former returns.

Comment: But for integer inputs it seems correct: `Nearest[Range[6], 3, {10, 2}] == 
 Nearest[Range[6], 3, {10, 2}, DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)] (* True *)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be because of the data v contains Integer numbers and real numbers.

check this

```
v2=DeleteCases[v, _Integer];
Nearest[v2, 39.28, {6, 8.56}]
(*{39.28, 33.81, 33.56, 32.47, 31.12}*)

Nearest[N[v], 39.28, {6, 8.56}]   (*@ilian*)
(*{39.28, 33.81, 33.56, 32.47, 31.12}*)
```

Comment: Could also use `N[v]` instead of `v2`.

Comment: yes that can be done.

Comment: Both seem to be missing 30.72.

Comment: Than is because of precision. check this `Nearest[N[v], 39.28, {6, 8.561}]`

Comment: Good observation! I guess Mathematica get confused when seeing Integer, which cause a distance-function not able to deal with Real being chosen.

Answer (score 4):

It's a rounding problem. Try (Working on V9):

```
Nearest[Rationalize@v, Rationalize@39.28, {6, Rationalize@8.56}] // N
(*
  {39.28, 33.81, 33.56, 32.47, 31.12, 30.72}
*)
```

Comment: This only returns `{39.28}` for me in v10.2.

Comment: @It'sPronouncedOiler Surely a version bug!

Comment: Actually `Nearest[v, 39.28, {6, 9}]` gives the same result (`{39.28}`) on 10.2, so it may not a rounding problem.