# Why does Nearest not support Sqrt?

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, nearest

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

Simple examples with two points

```
nf1=Nearest[{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}]

nf1[{0, 0}, {All, 2.1}]
```

gives

```
{{0, 0}}
```

This is incorrect. If we test bigger radius, we can find that Mathematica takes 4 as critical radius. Because `nf1[{0, 0}, {All, 3.999}]` gives `{{0,0}}` and `nf1[{0, 0}, {All, 4}]` gives `{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}`. Why?

While if we use `N`

```
nf2 = Nearest[N@{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}]
nf2[{0, 0}, {All, 2.1}]
```

gives correct answer

```
{{0., 0.}, {1.41421, 1.41421}}
```

Why `Nearest` gives wrong answer with irrational number? And If `Nearest` doesn't support irrational number, is it possible to write another `Nearest` function that has the same behavior and same efficiency while supporting irrational number directly.

Comment: [Pssoibly related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95229/30913).

Comment: I also tested the workaround I gave in that question on your problem. `nf=Nearest[{{0,0},(Sqrt[2],Sqrt[2]}}, DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)]` generates a `NearestFunction` which returns the expected points for `nf[{0, 0}, {All, 2.1}]` (at least in v10.2).

Comment: @IPoiler This works! Good job! Thank you

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the development version.

Comment: Added the **bugs** tag then

Comment: @IPoiler So what is the conclusion at this moment? Is this a bug or not? I read your link, Algohi's observation is quite strange. If a `Nearest` function confused with Integers and Reals, I think it is not a good `Nearest`, what do you think?

Comment: @ilian development version is 10.3 or 11?

Comment: I assume it means that it's still a bug in the current release, but that a fix has been implemented and will be available in the next release.

Comment: Development version is 10.2+a decimal to be named later

Comment: Yes, the fix should be available in the [next release](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn103.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.3.

```
$Version

(* "10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)

nf1 = Nearest[{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}];
nf1[{0, 0}, {All, 2.1}]

(* {{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}} *)
```