# issue with `Nearest` with mixed type input

Tags: functions, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.2**

---

See if anyone else can reproduce this error:

```
 list = Join[{{0, 0}}, RandomReal[250 {-1, 1}, {3, 2}]]
 Nearest[list, RandomReal[250 {-1, 1}, 2], {1, 30}]
```

causes a consistent kernel crash. v10.1/windows.

making `list` all numeric makes it work fine:

```
 Nearest[N@list, RandomReal[250 {-1, 1}, 2], {1, 30}]
```

(Its the combination of the mixed type with that list-type third argument that seems to be the trouble )

Comment: Can not confirm. v10.0.1.0/Win7(64bit)

Comment: No problems in 10.3.

Comment: Confirm with 10.1 on Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the crash is a bug and has been fixed as of version 10.2. But I would recommend upgrading to 10.3 to avoid running into [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95229/) `Nearest` problem.

Possible workarounds for 10.0.2 or 10.1 include applying `N` as shown in the question, or specifying `DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)`.